# Predicting values for new records in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a data.frame, with 24 entries and 4 columns - 3 of which are values and fourth is a category, either 1 or 2.

I have another 4 elements for which I know the 3 values for, but not the category, and I want my program to try and fit them into one of the categories, based on my data.frame

How do I go about that? I've read about fuctions lm and predict, which I think that could help, but I have trouble fitting my data.frame into

Comment: You probably can try logistic regression model ( `glm()`) or other appropriate classification model to solve a classification problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want to do this in R.

Assuming your first 3 columns can predict the fourth column (i.e, there is some pattern by which the category of an observation is related to one or more of those 3 columns), you should be able to use something like multiple logistic regression to predict the 4th column based on the first 3 columns. Without more knowledge of your data, it will be difficult to give an exact answer, so this will be a barebones way of getting what you're looking for.

First, I would try looking into the glm() function for fitting a logistic model, for example:

```
fit <- glm(4thcolumnname ~ column1 + column2 + column3, data = data.frame, family = "binomial")
```

With that, you can use the Anova and or_glm functions to get a good summary of the model:

```
library(oddsratio)
library(car)
Anova(fit) #shows which variables (columns) are significant
or_glm(data = data.frame, model = fit, incr = list(column1 = 1)) #shows odds ratios for each variable, which can make interpretation easy. The incr argument depends on your variables, so you'll need to read the documentation of or_glm for that
```

For the purposes of refining your model, I'd recommend reading up on machine learning (https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/machine-learning-in-r could be a good resource).

Once you have a good model, you can use the predict function to predict new data. In this case, I'd recommend creating a new data frame with your new data and using that in the predict.glm() function:

```
new.data = data.frame[25:28,1:3] #subsets your data frame to get only the unknown data
predict.glm(fit, newdata = new.data, type = "response") #will give you the probability of each new data point being either 1 or 0
```

Hope that helps. If you want a more detailed answer, please provide some example code to show what you have already tried, as well as the nature of your data.